# Lua access indeces from table generated from JSON

Tags: json, lua, decode, lua-table, opencomputers

So, I am bound to use Lua for getting weather data from the Openweathermap API.
I managed to send a http request to return and store all data but now I am stuck with a Lua table I don't know how work with. I am very new to Lua and I didn't find any guide or similar regarding such a deep nested table in Lua.

In particular I am just interested in the field called temp in main. Here is a sample response from the API: [Sample request response](https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=524901&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1)

The dependencies are Lua's socket.http and [this](https://github.com/rxi/json.lua/blob/master/json.lua) json to Lua table formatter.
Here is my basic code structure

```
json = require ("json")
web = require ("socket.http")

local get = json.decode(web.request(<API Link>))
```

"get" now stores a table I don't know how to work with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 days I finally found the error. I was working in a Minecraft Mod called OpenComputers which utilizes Lua. It seems like the mod uses a own version of socket.http and every time I wanted to print the response it returned two functions to use with request. I found out that if I put a "()" after the variable it returned the Response as a String and with the JSON library I could decode it into a workable table.

Side note: I could access the weather like this: json_table["weather"]["temp"]

The mod is pretty poorly documented on the http requests so I had to figure this out by myslef. Thanks for your responses, in the end the error was as always very unexpected!

Comment: `()` attempts to invoke a value as a function. (It goes after an expression, of which a variable is a special case.)

Comment: This concept isn't really known to me since I mainly code in Java so thanks for clarifying that

Comment: Yes, functions are values and when attempting to call a value as a function you can pass whatever list of zero or more parameters you think are appropriate. The result will be a list of zero or more values, _potentially_ a different number for each call. So, you are right; Documentation is very important.

Comment: next time you could simply share the error message... error: attempt to index a function value is something different from "I don't know how to work with Lua tables".
If you're not sure what type a function returns just print the function call

Comment: @Piglet The weird part was it didn't print the function but a table containing two functions. So it showed to me as a table and I thought the request fetched the JSON as a table. There was no error I just couldn't access any values since I didn't know the keys. After I used pairs it printed two function definitions that where I got confused since I expected the JSON entries

Comment: @Xore print unknown tables `for k,v in pairs(someTable) do print(k,v) end`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know how to work with Lua tables you probably should learn the very basics of Lua. Refer to https://www.lua.org/start.html

The json string encodes a Lua table with all it's keys and values.

You can either read how the encoder encodes a table or you simply encode your own table and analyze the resulting json string.

```
print(json.encode({1,2,3}))
```

[1,2,3]

```
print(json.encode({a=1, b={1,2}, [3]="test"}))
```

{"3":"test","b":[1,2],"a":1}

and so on...

There's always table keys and values, separated by a colon.
Values can be numbers, strings, tables...
If the table only has numeric keys starting from one the value is a list of those values in brackets. If you have different keys in a table its encapsulated in curly brackets...

So let's have a look at your results. I'll remove 39 of the 40 entries to shorten it. I'll also indent to make the structure a bit more readable.

```
{
  "cod":"200",
  "message":0.0036,
  "cnt":40,
  "list":[{
          "dt":1485799200,
          "main":{
                 "temp":261.45,
                 "temp_min":259.086,
                 "temp_max":261.45,
                 "pressure":1023.48,
                 "sea_level":1045.39,
                 "grnd_level":1023.48,
                 "humidity":79,
                 "temp_kf":2.37},
                 "weather":[
                          {
                           "id":800,
                           "main":"Clear",
                           "description":"clear sky",
                           "icon":"02n"
                           }],
                 "clouds":{"all":8},
                 "wind":{"speed":4.77,"deg":232.505},
                 "snow":{},
                 "sys":{"pod":"n"},
                 "dt_txt":"2017-01-30 18:00:00"}
       ],
  "city":{
        "id":524901,
        "name":"Moscow",
        "coord":{
               "lat":55.7522,
               "lon":37.6156
         },

        "country":"none"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the help of https://www.json2yaml.com/, the structure is:

```
cod: '200'
message: 0.0036
cnt: 40
list:
- dt: 1485799200
  main:
    temp: 261.45
    temp_min: 259.086
    temp_max: 261.45
    pressure: 1023.48
    sea_level: 1045.39
    grnd_level: 1023.48
    humidity: 79
    temp_kf: 2.37
  weather:
  - id: 800
    main: Clear
    description: clear sky
    icon: 02n
  clouds:
    all: 8
  wind:
    speed: 4.77
    deg: 232.505
  snow: {}
  sys:
    pod: n
  dt_txt: '2017-01-30 18:00:00'
…
- dt: 1486220400
…
city:
  id: 524901
  name: Moscow
  coord:
    lat: 55.7522
    lon: 37.6156
  country: none
```

So,

```
for index, entry in ipairs(get.list) do
    print(index, entry.dt, entry.main.temp)
end
```

`ipairs` iterates over the positive integer keys in the table, up to but not including the first integer without a value. It seems that's the way the JSON library represent a JSON array.

Comment: This returned me two functions appliable on the request and I used: web.request(URL)() <- I added paranthesis. This gave me the JSON as a String which I could use in serialization afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

That sample response appears to have many subtables that have a `main` in them. Try this: `get.list[1].main.temp`.